# Exclude option from collection.map in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a line like this:

```
<%= f.input :state_id, :input_html => {:value => (policy_address.state.name rescue nil)}, :required => true, :collection => states.map {|s| [ s.name, s.id] }, :include_blank => 'Please select'%>
```

I want to exclude a value from the `states.map` collection. I thought that this would work but it doesn't:

```
<%= f.input :state_id, :input_html => {:value => (policy_address.state.name rescue nil)}, :required => true, :collection => states.map {|s| [ s.name, s.id] unless s.name == "excluded_state" }, :include_blank => 'Please select'%>
```

I put in `unless s.name == "excluded_state`, but, again, it's not working:

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`map` doesn't allow to skip values. You have to reject unwanted elements first.

```
states.reject { |s| s.name == "excluded_state" }.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }
```

Another (dirtier) solution is to return `nil` for excluded elements and use `Array#compact` on the resulting array to remove those `nil` elements:

```
states.map { |s| s.name == "excluded_state" ? nil : [s.name, s.id] }.compact
```

Comment: `states.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] if s.name == "excluded_state" }.compact`

Comment: Bonus points for adding that `#compact` works as well, but is a dirtier trick.

Answer (score 6):

[Eureka's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/537873/eureka) answer is good but here is just a brief explanation to clarify what's going on.

`map` returns a new array with the results of running block once for *every* element in the array. When you write `[s.name, s.id] unless s.name == "excluded_state"` this causes the block to return `nil` when `s.name == "excluded_state"` i.e. the result would be something like

```
[["NY", 1], nil, ["CA", 2]]
```

So you could use `reject` to remove the unwanted state first, or you could just use `compact`<sup>1</sup> to remove the `nil` entry on the result of your `map` as you originally wrote it.

---

1. `Array#compact` returns a copy of the array with all `nil` elements removed.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, It makes a lot more sense now why I was getting the error I got when I tried what I did.

Comment: Thanks: Condition order fixed, my mental parser ran too fast on this one ;)

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative to the provided answers is to use `each_with_item` in place of `map`

```
states.each_with_item([]) { |out, s| out << [s.name, s.id] unless s.name == "excluded_state" }
```

It's kind of a halfway between `each` and `reduce`/`inject`. It takes an argument in, iterates over your enumerable providing the argument and the element, then returns the argument at the end. You can manipulate the argument in the loop (it wouldn't make much sense not to).