# Rails4 - How to drop an option from select based on the value?

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

How do I drop an item from the following based on the value?

```
<%= select_tag :langlevel, options_for_select(Level.order(:name).map {|item| [item.name, item.id]}), id: 'langlevel_id', :class => 'form-control lang' %>
```

It gives me this

```
<select class="form-control lang" id="langlevel_id" name="langlevel"><option value="2">A1:Beginner</option>
<option value="3">A2:Elementary</option>
<option value="4">B1:Pre-Intermediate</option>
<option value="5">B2:Intermediate</option>
<option value="6">C1:Upper Intermediate</option>
<option value="7">C2:Advanced</option>
<option value="1">Native</option></select>
```

I want to remove the option "Native" which has value="1". I mean I do not want it to displayed at a place.

```
<option value="1">Native</option></select>
```

Kindly help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [where not](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#not-conditions) and exclude level with id 1

```
<%= select_tag :langlevel, options_for_select(Level.where.not(:id => 1).order(:name).map {|item| [item.name, item.id]}), id: 'langlevel_id', :class => 'form-control lang' %>
```

Its probably cleaner to move this logic to helper

```
def non_native_levels_as_options
   Level.where.not(:id => 1).order(:name).map {|item| [item.name, item.id]}
end

<%= select_tag :langlevel, options_for_select(non_native_levels_as_options), id: 'langlevel_id', :class => 'form-control lang' %>
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Thanks for sharing the best practices way of moving it to helper

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should work:

```
<%= select_tag :langlevel, options_for_select(Level.all.order(:name).reject { |s| s.id == 1 }.map {|item| [item.name, item.id]}), id: 'langlevel_id', :class => 'form-control lang' %>
```

You have to reject first and then map.

From here: [Exclude option from collection.map in Ruby on Rails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12408561/exclude-option-from-collection-map-in-ruby-on-rails)

Comment: @Vimsha answer's better than mine ;)